# Submit VBArray of Binary data to MVC 3 using JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, arrays

I am using an activex control to get images from a hardware device (front and back).  These images are created as a VBArray.

```
data = {
    FrontImageData: scanResult.MemoryScanResult.FrontImageTiff.toArray(),
    BackImageData: scanResult.MemoryScanResult.BackImageTiff.toArray(),
};
```

This puts the VBArray into an array in my json object.

It's your standard binary/integer array.  I am doing an ajax post to my server, which works fine.  The problem is on the backend.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SubmitItem(SubmitItemRequest request)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
```

And my model.  There is other data that I am passing in through my ajax post, but it isn't important.

```
public class SubmitCheckRequest
{
    public byte[] FrontImageData { get; set; }
    public byte[] BackImageData { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that my front and back images are coming to the server as null.  When I evaluate the Request, the data is there, but MVC is not translating the data correctly into my model.

Maybe the problem is how the 'VBArray' is being translated into the array?  Any ideas how to get the binary data to the server so I can save the images along with the meta data?

Comment: In your action method, check the Request.Form to see if the data is arriving at the server.  If it is, it's a model binding issue, possibly ASP.NET MVC isn't recognizing the VBArray as a byte[].